# How to centralize and specialize error handling across different layers in a multi-layered architecture?

Tags: clean-architecture

I'm working on a project with a multi-layered architecture consisting of four main layers: domain, application, infrastructure, and presentation/REST. In the application layer, I have my use cases where I coordinate all the business logic using Input Ports and Output Ports.

When a use case is executed, various errors can occur, originating from the domain layer, infrastructure layer, or even from the use case class itself.

How can I centralize and specialize error handling for these situations?

My question is not related how to present it. I mean, I have a usecasePresenterOutput like this:

```java
public interface CreateReferencePresenterOutputPort<T> {

    T success(CreateReferenceResult createReferenceResult);

    T presentPersistenceError(CreateReferencePersistenceError createReferencePersistenceError);

    T presentReferencedDocumentIdNotExists(
            CreateReferenceReferencedDocumentIdNotExistsError createReferenceReferencedDocumentIdNotExists);

    T presentInvalidInputError(CreateReferenceInputError createReferenceInputError);

   ...

}
```

My question is overall centralized on how to handle infrastructure exceptions. I mean, there (on infrastructure layer) a lot of exceptions types can be raised, `IOException`, `NoSuchAlgortihm`, and a long list of any type of exception.

How could I properly handle them into my use-case class?

I want to ensure that:

1. Errors are handled appropriately at each layer without leaking implementation details.
2. Error handling logic is centralized to avoid duplication and maintainability issues.
3. Different types of errors can be handled differently based on the context, such as retrying certain operations, logging specific errors, or presenting user-friendly error messages.
4. I'm looking for best practices or design patterns to achieve this in a clean and maintainable way. Should I use exception wrapping and rethrowing, custom error classes, or some other approach? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!